# What is the difference between echo $var and echo "$var"

Tags: bash

On the terminal (bash) when I type

```
var=someValue

echo $var    --> 1
echo "$var"  --> 2
```

> Form 1 and 2 I get the same results, so what is the difference between
>   them?
>
> When should we use double quotes, and when should we not use them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference between `echo $var` and `echo "$var"`.

However for other commands such as `ls` (list files) there could be a big difference.

Try this in your terminal:

```
$ touch "File A"

$ var="File A"

$ ls $var
ls: cannot access 'File': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'A': No such file or directory

$ ls "$var"
File A
```

The double quotes `"` tells Linux to treat everything in between as a single entity. Without the double quotes everything inside is treated as separate entities delineated by spaces.

So in the first example `$var` is two different things "File" and "A".

In the second example `"$var"` is one thing `"File A"`.

The `echo` command automatically processes a single word or multiple words until the end of the line as one thing. Many other commands expect one or many things.

Answer (score 0):

The difference comes when you store a multi line string in a variable and try to echo it.

Try this:

```
$var="this is a
line of
code"

$ echo $var
this is a line of code

$ echo "$var"
this is a
line of
code
```